# How can I create a pop up window in login form using HTML CSS?

Tags: html, css, forms, popupwindow

I'm a beginner in HTML CSS and I'm working on a project where I have created a purchase form where a person writes data like address phone number zip code to purchase products . When a person fills all the required fields and presses a button to complete his purchase I would like to pop up a small window which says purchase complete ! I can only use use html and css for this project and I would appreciate your help with giving me some guidelines to create the pop up window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edited the code and created a popup with simple CSS and HTML with no JavaScript. It is as good as the JavaScript one. Check it out:

```css
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Pure css popup box</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>
<div class="box">
 <a class="button" href="#popup1">Let me Pop up</a>
</div>

<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
 <div class="popup">
  <h4>Purchase Complete</h4>
  <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
 </div>
</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I cannot . I am at college and we haven't learned yet .

Comment: I have changed the code and now there is only HTML and CSS. Check it out.

Comment: Thank you very much